# django - limit the number of users

Tags: django

(sorry for my english)

Only a question, exist any way to limit the number of users that can be created in a Django App?

I search in a lot of places and i only find this, but i see in the repo that the last update was 3 years ago https://github.com/1stvamp/django-limit-users

I don't know if exist any way in the core of django or if i have to override something!

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't have time to test https://github.com/1stvamp/django-limit-users against a new Django, it goes in the right direction using django's signals: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/

So for example, you could write a `pre_save` or a `post_save` handler and connect it to the signals emitted before / after saving your user model.

A simple `post_save` handler could look like:

```
def user_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and sender.objects.count() > MY_LIMIT:
        instance.is_active = False
        instance.save()
```

A simple `pre_save` handler would look like:

```
def user_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.id is None and sender.objects.count() > MY_LIMIT:
        instance.is_active = False  # Make sure the user isn't active
```

Instead of the last line in the `pre_save` handler, you could also raise an Exception to make sure the User isn't even saved to the DB.

Another option would be to combine this with a custom user model so instead of `is_active` you could use  `over_limit` or whatever you want. The repo you linked is achieving that with a separate `DisabledUser` model.

Comment: Now is very late, but tomorrow i going to try django-limit-users if not work make it my own. Thanks !!!