# Limit the amount of user registration in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, saas

I am newbie in django a I have a question. My system, developed in django, needs to register only the amount of user given in a registration page. How I do to verificate and to limit the amount of registered user?

The system has 2 page, basically: on a page, the user inputs the maximum amount of users who can register in the system. On the other page, users are registered, with the limitation given on the previous page.

The field of dabatase that stores the maximum value is CadastroCliente.qtde_usuarios

Follow my view:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

from apps.criarusuario.forms import SignUpForm

from apps.cadastro.models import CadastroCliente # table with amount of users to be registered in the system

@login_required
def signup(request):
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    count = CadastroCliente.qtde_usuarios #store the size of registered user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            if (CadastroCliente.qtde_usuarios == count): #verify the amout???
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
        else:
            if (CadastroCliente.qtde_usuarios == count): #verify the amout ??
               form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'criarusuario/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

CadastroCliente Model:

```
class CadastroCliente(models.Model):
    qtde_usuarios = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Limit user Registration: ',
                                                validators=[MinValueValidator(1)],
                                                null=False, blank=False)
```

View of CadastroCreate, in this page, the user sets the limit of user registration

```
class CadastroCreate(CreateView):
    model = CadastroCliente
    fields = [
             'qtde_usuarios'
             ]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273666/django-limit-the-number-of-users) . It might help.

Comment: Capture guest ip and limit one login per ip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main problems is that you are attempting to access the `qtde_usuarios` value without specifying which specific instance it is stored in. This is what causes the `DeferredAttribute` error you mentioned in the comments:

```py
CadastroCliente.qtde_usuarios  # this won't work
CadastroCliente.objects.first().qtde_usuarios  # this might
```

The next problem is that you are using a `CreateView` to set your `qtde_usuarios` value. Every time you use this view it creates a new record in the database. It would be better to maintain a single record and update it.

You should be able to handle things as follows:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
# other imports


class SetLimitView(UpdateView):
    fields = ['qtde_usuarios']
    success_url = '/'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        """Use the first object or create new."""
        return CadastroCliente.objects.first() or CadastroCliente()

@login_required
def signup(request):
    form = SignUpForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_model = get_user_model()
            qtde_usuarios = CadastroCliente.objects.first().qtde_usuarios
            if (user_model.objects.all().count() <= qtde_usuarios):
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
    return render(request, 'criarusuario/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for helping me.... Your logic is correct, but even though I input a user limit to be registered in the "qtde_usuarios" field, the system allows me to register as many users as I want... For example, I insert 2 users in "qtde_usuarios" and the system allows me to unlimited users. Could you help me?

Comment: @gPxl No problem. Your question states that you have 2 pages. Can you update your question to include the other view which is used to set the `qtde_usuarios` value?

Comment: Hi... I include the model of CadastroCliente, thank you very much!

Comment: @gPxl Thanks. I think we all thought you were saving your new users to `CadastroCliente`. Are you saving them to the default Django `User`?

Comment: Hi... sorry for the mess... Yes, in the 'CadastroCliente' I just store the maximum users allowed to register in the system. And the users I saving them to the default Django User.

Comment: Can I use this statement to verify and save the users?
     if (get_user_model().objects.all().count() <= qtde_usuarios):
                form.save()

Comment: @gPxl Yes that would work once you have the correct `qtde_usuarios` value. I've updated my answer with some more detail.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count no of Users in your system:

```
CadastroCliente.objects.all().count()
```

it will return Integer value.

Comment: Thank you for helping! But I am facing this error "TypeError at /criarusuario/
'>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'DeferredAttribute'" I wrote in my code: 
count = CadastroCliente.qtde_usuarios #amout registered by user to limit the user registration in the system
if (CadastroCliente.objects.all().count() >= count):
 ...

Comment: tell me details, what is this ?
"CadastroCliente.qtde_usuarios"

Comment: "CadastroCliente" is a model and "qtde_usuarios" is a field of the CadastroCliente. In the "qtde_usuarios" the user input the maximum users to be registered in the system.

Comment: `CadastroCliente.objects.first().qtde_usuarios` or `CadastroCliente.objects.get(pk=123).qtde_usuarios`

Answer (score 0):

I just modify your code to fit your requirement.Please check and confirm

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

from apps.criarusuario.forms import SignUpForm

from apps.cadastro.models import CadastroCliente # table with amount of users to be registered in the system

@login_required
def signup(request):
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    user_Count = CadastroCliente.objects.all().count()
    count = CadastroCliente.qtde_usuarios #store the size of registered user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            if (CadastroCliente.qtde_usuarios == count): #verify the amout???
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
        else:
            if (user_Count < count): #Here you are allowing to show form if user_count is less then user limit
               form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'criarusuario/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple post_save handler could look like:

```
def user_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and sender.objects.count() > MY_LIMIT:
        instance.is_active = False
        instance.save()
```

A simple pre_save handler would look like:

```
def user_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.id is None and sender.objects.count() > MY_LIMIT:
        instance.is_active = False  # Make sure the user isn't active
```